# Proving existence of a sequence limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $(a_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ and $(b_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ be two sequences that are defined by the recursive formulas
>
> \begin{cases}
> 0 \lt b_1 \lt a_1\\
> a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}, &b_{n+1}=\frac{2a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n} & \forall n\in\mathbb{N}
> \end{cases}

I'm having trouble with some questions regarding these two sequences.
First I have to show they are well defined and I'm a bit lost on the procedure to prove such a thing.

Second, given that $a_{n+1\ }\ge b_{n+1}$ for every $n$, I need to show that the limits of the sequences are equal and converge to some $L$, my plan was to show that one of the sequences converges by the definition of limit but I'm having trouble proving it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $(a_n)_n$ and $(b_n)_n$ are well-defined it pretty obvious, since one can see by an easy induction that $a_n, b_n>0$, for all $n\ge 0$.

The fact that $a_n\ge b_n$ for all $n \ge 0$ is again pretty obvious, since $(\forall) x,y >0$:
$$\frac{x+y}{2} \ge \frac{2xy}{x+y} \iff (x+y)^2 \ge 4xy \iff (x-y)^2\ge 0 \text{ which is true}$$
In fact, this inequality says that the arithmetic mean of $x,y $ is greater or equal to the harmonic mean of $x,y$.

Now, remark that $$a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n+b_n}{2} \le \frac{a_n+a_n}{2} = a_n$$ and $$b_{n+1} = \frac{2a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n} = \frac{2}{\frac{1}{a_n}+\frac{1}{b_n}} \ge \frac{2}{\frac{1}{b_n}+\frac{1}{b_n}} = b_n$$
Therefore, one has
$$b_1 \le b_2 \le \ldots \le b_n \le a_n \le a_{n-1} \le \ldots \le a_1$$ for all $n\ge 1$. Thus, the sequences $(a_n)_n$ and $(b_n)_n$ are monotone and bounded, hence convergent. Let $l_1 = \lim_\limits{n \to \infty} a_n$ and $l_2 = \lim_\limits{n \to \infty} b_n$. Now, passing to limit in $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n+b_n}{2}$, we get $l_1 = \frac{l_1+l_2}{2}$, i.e. $l_1 = l_2$, Q.E.D.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
To show thay are well defined, you need to check that $a_n+b_n$ can't be $0$ (for all $n \geq 1$), so $\left(b_n\right)$ exists.

For the limit, you might notice that
$$
a_{n+1}b_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}\times\frac{2a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n}=a_nb_n
$$
(under condition you've proved that $a_n+b_n \ne 0$ for all $n \geq 1$).
The you can deduce that

$$
a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(a_n+\frac{a_1b_1}{a_n}\right)
$$
And maybe you know this type of sequences ? This is a "Babylon Algorithm".

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! :) don't I need to prove one of a,n / b,n converges before I use that fact?

Comment: The fact is true for all $n$ and will help you show that either $(a_n)$ or $(b_n)$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

To show that the sequences are well defined, you can proceed by induction using AM-GM: $\frac{a+b}2\geq \sqrt{ab}$ for $a,b>0$ where equality holds if and only if $a=b$:

$$0<b_n < a_n \Rightarrow b_n < a_{n+1}= \frac{a_n+b_n}2 < a_n$$

and

$$b_{n+1} = \frac 2{a_{n}+b_n}a_nb_n > \frac 2{a_{n}+a_n}a_nb_n = b_n$$

and

$$b_{n+1} =\frac 2{a_{n}+b_n}a_nb_n \stackrel{AM-GM}{<} \frac{a_nb_n}{\sqrt{a_nb_n}}=\sqrt{a_nb_n}\stackrel{GM-AM}{<}\frac{a_n+b_n}2 = a_{n+1}$$

All together
$$0 < b_n < a_n \Rightarrow b_n < b_{n+1} < a_{n+1} < a_n $$

Hence, the recursion is well defined.

Now, you have bounded monotonous sequences. Hence, the limits
$a=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n$ and $b=\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n$ exist.

With $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n+b_n}2$ and using limit laws you get

$$a = \frac{a+b}2 \Leftrightarrow a=b$$